# Error funcion editar Laravel

Tags: laravel

Buanas estoy trabajando en un proyecto para entrgar de una automotora, quiero editar modelos de los autos. este es mi codigo del controller:

```
public function showModelEdit($id)
    {
        $model = CarModel::find($id);
        $brand = Brand::all();
        return view('admin/modelEdit', [
            'models' => $model,
            'brands' => $brand,

        ]);


public function editModel(Request $request, $id)

    {
        $model = CarModel::find($id);
        $model->name = $request->name;
        $model->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
        $model->save();
        return redirect('admin/modelos')->with('mensaje', "El artículo $model->id fue actualizado exitosamente.");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error?

Comment: muestra que tienes en `modelEdit.blade.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Blade estas poniendo `$model->id` en el form y desde el controlador envías `'models' => $model,`.

Reemplazar models por model en el controlador creo que sería lo mas adecuado:

```
public function showModelEdit($id)
{
    $model = CarModel::find($id);
    $brand = Brand::all();
    return view('admin/modelEdit', [
        'model' => $model, // <- aquí!
        'brands' => $brand,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Impecable, funciono gracias!!